# Using Regular Expressions to extract specific urls in python

Tags: python, regex

I have parsed an html document containing javascript with beautifulsoup, and have managed to isolate the javascript within it and convert it into a string. The javascript looks like this:

```
<script>
    [irrelevant javascript code here]
    sources:[{file:"http://url.com/folder1/v.html",label:"label1"},
    {file:"http://url.com/folder2/v.html",label:"label2"},
    {file:"http://url.com/folder3/v.html",label:"label3"}],
    [irrelevant javascript code here]
</script>
```

I am trying to get an array with only urls contained in this sources array, which would look like so:

```
urls = ['http://url.com/folder1/v.html', 
        'http://url.com/folder2/v.html', 
        'http://url.com/folder3/v.html']
```

The domains are unknown IPs, the folders are of random name-length consisting of lowercase letters and numbers, and there are 1-5 of them in each file(usually 3). All that is constant is that they start with `http` and end with `.html`.

I decided to use regular expressions to deal with this problem(which I am quite new at) and my code looks like this: `urls=re.findall(r'http://[^t][^s"]+', document)`

The `[^t]` is there because there are other urls in the document whose domain names start with t. My problem is, there is another url with a jpg from the same domain as the urls I am extracting, which gets put into the urls array along with the others.

Example:

```
urls = ['http://123.45.67.89/asodibfo3ribawoifbadsoifasdf3/v.html'
        'http://123.45.67.89/alwefaoewifiasdof224a/v.html',
        'http://123.45.67.89/baoisdbfai235oubodsfb45/v.html',
        'http://123.45.67.89/i/0123/12345/aoief243oinsdf.jpg']
```

How would I go about only fetching the html urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `r'"(http.*?)"'` to get the urls within your text :

```
>>> s="""<script>
...     [irrelevant javascript code here]
...     sources:[{file:"http://url.com/folder1/v.html",label:"label1"},
...     {file:"http://url.com/folder2/v.html",label:"label2"},
...     {file:"http://url.com/folder3/v.html",label:"label3"}],
...     [irrelevant javascript code here]
... </script>"""

>>> re.findall(r'"(http.*?)"',s,re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
['http://url.com/folder1/v.html', 'http://url.com/folder2/v.html', 'http://url.com/folder3/v.html']
```

ans for extracting the `.html`'s in list of urls you can use `str.endswith` :

```
>>> urls = ['http://123.45.67.89/asodibfo3ribawoifbadsoifasdf3/v.html',
...         'http://123.45.67.89/alwefaoewifiasdof224a/v.html',
...         'http://123.45.67.89/baoisdbfai235oubodsfb45/v.html',
...         'http://123.45.67.89/i/0123/12345/aoief243oinsdf.jpg']
>>> 
>>> [i for i in urls if i.endswith('html')]
['http://123.45.67.89/asodibfo3ribawoifbadsoifasdf3/v.html', 
 'http://123.45.67.89/alwefaoewifiasdof224a/v.html', 
 'http://123.45.67.89/baoisdbfai235oubodsfb45/v.html']
```

Also as another general and flexible way for such tasks you can use [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) module :

```
>>> from fnmatch import fnmatch
>>> [i for i in urls if fnmatch(i,'*.html')]
['http://123.45.67.89/asodibfo3ribawoifbadsoifasdf3/v.html', 
 'http://123.45.67.89/alwefaoewifiasdof224a/v.html', 
 'http://123.45.67.89/baoisdbfai235oubodsfb45/v.html']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same with `{file:url`look for the substring between quotes following  `{file:`:

```
s="""<script>
    [irrelevant javascript code here]
    sources:[{file:"http://url.com/folder1/v.html",label:"label1"},
    {file:"http://url.com/folder2/v.html",label:"label2"},
    {file:"http://url.com/folder3/v.html",label:"label3"}],
    [irrelevant javascript code here]
</script>"""


print(re.findall("\{file\:\"(.*?)\"",s))
['http://url.com/folder1/v.html', 'http://url.com/folder2/v.html', 'http://url.com/folder3/v.html']
```

You could also limit your strings to search by splitting once on sources:

```
s="""<script>
    [irrelevant javascript code here]
    sources:[{file:"http://url.com/folder1/v.html",label:"label1"},
    {file:"http://url.com/folder2/v.html",label:"label2"},
    {file:"http://url.com/folder3/v.html",label:"label3"}],
    [irrelevant javascript code here]
</script>"""

print(re.findall("\{file\:\"(.*?)\"",s.split("sources:[",1)[1]))
```

Which would remove all the other lines before `sources:[`, presuming there are not other `sources:[`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
re.findall(r'http://[^t][^s"]+\.html', document)
```